# Chartkick rails 4 and table charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-visualization, chartkick

I can't seem to figure out how or if Chartkick supports table charts.  I tried table_chart as if I were doing any other chart, but it didn't work.  Anyone know if chartkick supports that?  I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as table chart in chartkick.

There are `line`, `pie`, `column`, `area`, `bar`, `geo` charts and `timeline` avaliable.

All kind of charts with usage explanations you can find on [chartkick official website](http://chartkick.com/).

Comment: That's too bad, I am going to have to try and figure out how to do google visualizations directly then for the table_chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can check kick chart for integration with rails
http://chartkick.com/

you can use like

```
for_line_chart
= line_chart Model.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>

pie_chart
= pie_chart Model.group(:field).count

column_chart
= column_chart Model.group_by_hour_of_day(:field).count

bar_chart
= bar_chart Model.group(:field).sum(:field)

area_chart
= area_chart Model.group_by_minute(:created_at).maximum(:field)


line_chart
= line_chart completed_tasks_charts_path
```

For more please consult the link shared above hopefully this will help you a lot.